# Solve Omega-notation

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms, asymptotics

How to Prove that (nlogn-10n+5)= Ω(nlogn)

I have tried to solve this question using limit rule but i am not getting correct answer for Ω notation. And second Question is that for f(n)>=c*g(n) value of c have to positive but by solving i am getting value of c is negative.
Is it possible to solve this problem? Please give the complete solution for (nlogn-10n+5)= Ω(nlogn).

Comment: What are you doing to "solve" and get a negative c?

Comment: by looking at problem i tried to get (nlogn-10n+5)>c*logn

Comment: Basic idea:  for large $n$, $5$ doesn't matter and $logn$ is much bigger than $10$, so $nlogn-10n+5$ behaves like $nlogn$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large $n$, $nlogn-10n+5\gt \frac{nlogn}{2}$.